# How send an http link in response using firebase cloud functions

Tags: html, node.js, request, google-cloud-functions, http-response-codes

Here is my function:

```
exports.onEmailVerified = functions.region('southamerica-east1').https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return res.status(200).send('html link to redirect')
})
```

how can be that the response be an beautiful html to open to user ?

Comment: What's wrong with just putting the URL where your string is now?  The code that calls this function will be able to find it and perform the redirect.  I think you might want to edit the question to provide more data about what you're trying to accomplish, and what you've tried that isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: so i just need to put my website link and the response redirect to it automatically ? I do not want to present 'string' to user, but a beaultiful html with css, etc.

Comment: my user is just seeing a string, i do want to show him a beaultiful html, but how i pass this html for him ? or a link redirect

Comment: So you're not calling this as an API from some other code?  You're sending the browser to the function's URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send an HTTP redirect like this:

```
res.redirect('the-url');
```

Comment: that's what i was looking for